# Time out while connecting to the database. Current time out value is 30 seconds

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, data-warehouse

I am installing a repository creation utility on a `windows 8 x64 bit` system and getting the following error:

> Time out while connecting to the database. Current time out value is 30 seconds

When I connect via sqdeveloper, it works fine.
My database connection details are:

```
- Database type: Oracle Database
- Host name: Bonge
- Port: 1521
- service name: XE
- Username: sys
- Password: XXXXX
- Role: Sysdba
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: This question doesn't give any indication of the troubleshooting steps you've already taken.  Can you let us know what you've already done?

Comment: Yeah. YOu can bet that most of the information you give are totally irrelevant - because any error in them would NOT result in a timeout but in a connection error for other reasons and with another error message. That said: 30 seconds for a connect is a high value. Not saying it is wrong - but this is one of the issues that never get hit because connects happen in a second or less.

Comment: What utility are you using?

Comment: Is that utility Java based? How is the connection string specified/configured? Does it really use a sysdba role?

Answer (score 1):

Better use TNSNAMES.ORA file in your client. You can set Instant Client's timeout in SQLNET.ORA file

%ORACLE_HOME%\admin\network\

ORACLE_HOME is where your Instant Client binaries are and should be already added to your local environment variables.

If you don't know what Instant Client is, it is a binary dll that provides connection, execution and fetching capabilities over network. sqldeveloper has a lite one inside it's "installation" (read unzipped) folder, but you either have to reference to that manually, or install a proper one yourself. It can be downloaded from Oracle.com

Answer (score 0):

To further supplement @Cunning's answer, connections made within SQL Developer default to a [Basic Connection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-may/o38sql-102034.html).  A *Basic Connection* doesn't use the `tnsnames.ora` file or any locally installed oracle client on the machine.  This is likely how you're able to connect to the database via SQL Developer without much issue.

You'll need to install an Oracle Client on the machine and likely create a tnsnames.ora entry for the server as well before rerunning your *repository creation utility*.  There are number of walkthroughs on how to do this, but [here's one I wrote on the 11g client for Windows](https://dbaeyes.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/soup-to-nuts-oracle-11g-client-on-windows/) if you're looking for something.  I doubt the 12c client is drastically different, but this should get you pointed toward the proper direction.